# Xcode 4: List Methods By Name?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there any way to navigate the structure of an Objective-C file by alpha order for the methods? The combobox (in the Jump Bar) that shows all the methods is not much more helpful than looking through the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Jump Bar Help Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-jump_bar/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010437-CH1-SW1):

> "Tip: Hold down the Command key when selecting a level in the path menu to view its items alphabetically."

[image: Screenshot for tip in Jump Bar Help Page]

Comment: Thanks @WrightsCS... I've started looking at the Jump Bar more carefully, and it's got a lot of features I didn't know about. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a file implementing a class then in the Symbol Navigator (CMD+2) you can expand the class you're interested in and the class's member variables and methods are listed in alphabetical order.

Comment: Any way to jump to the class that's currently open in the text editor?